# Suppress space after acronym

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package to keep a list of acronyms. In Dutch when you compose a word with an acronym you should use a hyphen to put the two words together. For example, an ARP table becomes ARP-tabel in Dutch. If I have defined the acronym 'ARP', how can I put the '-tabel' after it without a space being introduced by LaTeX?

This is what I have currently:

```
\gls{arp} -tabel
```

But produces:

```
ARP -tabel
```

What I want:

```
ARP-tabel
```

Comment: Write `\gls{arp}-tabel`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Gah, I can't believe that works Werner. I was sure I tried that and it ate part of the word after the acronym, but no, it works. I'm thoroughly ashamed now and I apologize for the stupid question...

Comment: Thank you Adam, I will keep that in mind for the next time I post a question. I thought it was best of me to keep the code as specific and small as possible, but forgot the preamble could be relevant as well.

Comment: Another possibility is to use `\gls{arp}[-tabel]` if you want `-tabel` included in the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a stupid question. `\gls` has the syntax `\gls[`*options*`]{`*label*`}[`*insert*`]`. In general, commands whose final argument is optional can have odd behaviour when the command is followed by a space. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\itest}[1][Foo]{#1}
\newcommand*{\otest}[1]{#1\itest}

\otest{X} 1. \otest{Y}[Bar] 2.

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: XFoo1. YBar 2.]

In the first case the space has been discarded but in the second case it hasn't. Since this isn't usually a desired effect for `\gls`, `glossaries` uses `amsgen`'s test for an optional argument which doesn't discard following spaces. So `\gls{arp} -tabel` doesn't ignore the space. As mentioned in the comments the solution is to either remove the space `\gls{arp}-tabel` or put the suffix in the optional argument `\gls{arp}[-tabel]`. The only thing you need to watch out for is if you want `[` immediately after `\gls{arp}`, in which case you'd have to do something like `\gls{arp}{}[` or `\gls{arp}{[}`.